# How can I resolve Azure basic function app error

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created one basic function app in VS2017 and tried run, facing
issue below.

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Fun
>   ction1.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'log' to type TraceWriter. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're
>   using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. config."

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

namespace FunctionAppLatest
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            // parse query parameter
            string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
                .Value;

            if (name == null)
            {
                // Get request body
                dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
                name = data?.name;
            }

            return name == null
                ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
                : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions 2.0 in Azure no longer use `TraceWriter`.

Please replace it by  `ILogger log`

Instead of `log.info` you will need to use `log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");`